# How to convert entries in a column to list in a cell in a table in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Say I have the an Access table called *tblFruitsColours* with two columns/fields: **Fruit** and **Colour**

**Fruit   | Colour**

Apple    | Red

Apple    | Green

Mango    | Yellow

Mango    | Green

Grapes   | Purple

I want to run an SQL that will create the following results (get the colours of the same fruit and list them in a cell separated by commas.

**Fruit    | Colours**

Apple     | Red, Green

Mango     | Yellow, Green

Grapes    | Purple

Any idea how to write the SQL?  Thanks in advance.